# How can I export a 3D model with keyframes to use in Blender?

Tags: 3d, blender, obj, export, asset-workflow

I'm currently trying to export some 3D data and load it into Blender, but I've encountered some problems at the time of processing the meshes. They all have keyframes (nothing too complex, just texture change and rotation) but I cannot use traditional Wavefront Obj to export it, because it does not support this data.

How can I export this keyframe information in a way Blender will understand?

Comment: Asking how you could fix the issues you encountered could be more on topic and potentially as helpful to you :)

Comment: Can you clarify, what are you exporting this data *from*?

Comment: @DMGregory I want to export it from a private format that I work with in my college for a practice.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - find out what formats Blender CAN import that support keyframes. Then use the spec to export it from your mesh library.

See my comments below, if you choose to use Collada, which is perfectly suitable for your purpose.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it helped identify an appropriate format.

Comment: I've already done my research... And most of the formats that I've seen are really complex. I believe that the "less" complex of them all is collada since it's ASCII. But further from this they'll support lot of stuff that I don't really want to mess with for the purpose of my practice.

Comment: Most things that are supported are still optional. You don't have to use features you don't need. That said, it looks like you might have better luck using a python script to import your data. Python can interface directly with Blender's API and set keyframes, as you asked for.

Comment: http://www.wazim.com/Collada_Tutorial_1.htm should help you get started understanding Collada, and of course use the spec itself https://www.khronos.org/collada/ if you decide to use the Collada format. There is also a C++ DOM for Collada to help you work with it.

Comment: @Onelio did you find a solution? Please share

Comment: Can we downvote downvotes please? wtf